# Relation between direction cosines

Tags: geometry

It is given in my textbook that direction cosines of a line are related to each other as:
$$l^2+m^2+n^2=1$$
Is there a proof for this relation?If there is,please provide a detailed step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Depending on your definition of direction cosine, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) provides a simple, but effective proof.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example and/or a sketch. Also, this is not specific to lines, but to direction vectors in general.